# Maven Could not transfer metadata

Tags: java, maven

I want to deploy this project on wildfly server

https://github.com/packt-wildfly/packt-java-ee-7-code-samples/tree/master/1980EN_03_Code/ticket-agency

and everythink is fine but when i want to mvn wildfly:deploy i get this error:

```
C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\Workspace\ticket-agency>mvn wildfly:deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] ticket-agency
[INFO] ticket-agency-ejb
[INFO] ticket-agency-ejb-client
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-metadata-central.xml (access forbidden)
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\maven-metadata-central.xml (access forbidden)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] ticket-agency ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ticket-agency-ejb .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ticket-agency-ejb-client ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.780 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-16T20:20:07+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'winlfly' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

I don't use PROXY on my home pc so setting.xml isn't important so much( i have proxy setting commented).

with -X command option:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'wildfly' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'wildfly' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:93)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:266)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:89)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

I have maven 3.3.3 from april so its one of newest versions.

More of the same debug option

```
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Maven\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from C:\Maven\bin\..\conf\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.packtpub.wflydevelopment.chapter3:ticket-agency:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.packtpub.wflydevelopment.chapter3:ticket-agency-ejb:ejb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging ejb from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.packtpub.wflydevelopment.chapter3:ticket-agency-ejb-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] ticket-agency
[INFO] ticket-agency-ejb
[INFO] ticket-agency-ejb-client
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix wildfly from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Failed to write checksum file C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\maven-metadata-central.xml.sha1: C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\maven-metadata-central.xml.sha1 (Odmowa dostępu)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\maven-metadata-central.xml.sha1 (Odmowa dostępu)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultFileProcessor.copy(DefaultFileProcessor.java:152)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultFileProcessor.copy(DefaultFileProcessor.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultFileProcessor.move(DefaultFileProcessor.java:211)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ChecksumValidator.commit(ChecksumValidator.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:475)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:607)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 28.8 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at 44.4 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\resolver-status.properties
```

Comment: did you mean `mvn wildfly:deploy`?  I don't see any windfly on google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whole project was wrong, I created new one from the existing project and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have Full Access to all folders in `C:\Users\Adam Kortylewicz\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\maven-metadata-central.xml`; one of them might not be writeable to you (or is not owned by you).

Comment: I have full control. Ay other idea?